# How to abort the ajax request halfway directly from browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to abort/cancel an ajax request halfway directly from my browser in any website. For example, when I hit the submit button from a contact form and the loading spinner is showing indicate that the form is processing.

So around this period is there any way that allow me to cancel the request from the browser tools which makes the spinner still loading and the form is not submitted eventually( which I think that will probably produce an error in the network tab of the developer tools).

*Note: this is just a curious question and for testing purpose.*

Comment: Not to my knowledge, unless the response takes awhile to come back most AJAX requests happen fairly quickly. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: For example you are developing yourself and you put and insane print out in the response and now it's taking forever to do the ajax request and blocking my web browser, I really would like to know the answer to this!

Answer (score 0):

if you are not expecting a return, why not just fake the call?

before the call gets made, type `return;` in the function. If you want the spinner action, change the cursor on body to `cursor: wait;` (i think that was the one)

Probably not understanding your question though... ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using vanilla JS, try [XMLHttpRequest.abort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#abort()). jQuery's `ajax` should also [still expose this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). You could verify that `readyState` of the XHR is `DONE` or that some other registered callback is invoked to test.